Get single post, based on a custom field value using url query params
In the post that I want to display I have a custom field (ACF) with a unique value set: member_id:'123456' So the url that I want to parse would look like this: https://my-site/my-post-type/?mid=123456
Before the page is displayed I want to use this field to get the page id belonging to the post, and then display that post.
What I have tried is to use:
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) { 
     if( isset($_GET['mid']) ) { 
          $query->set('meta_key', 'member_id'); 
          $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['mid']); 
     } 
} 

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts'); 

But this only filters an archive page to show the post that match the ACF field value. If I configure my custom post type to archive = true, which I do not want).
Maybe this 'pre_get_posts' action could work in a single page setting too? So is there a way to replace 'mid' in the url with the corresponding page id?

As per Wordpress pre_get_posts documentation, the hook is not feasible if it is being used to modify a single post or page query. You will need to directly query the custom key value via WP_Query at theme's page.php or single.php file.
Hope this helps.
